# Default translation support in Sitecore

Tags: multilingual

I am looking for translation features in Sitecore. Does Sitecore provide translation support out of box? 
I saw translate button in version tab but not sure what does it do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore does not provide any translation support out of box. You can use probably use ClayTablet (http://www.clay-tablet.com/products/cms-connectors/sitecore) or GlobalLink (http://www.translations.com/globallink/).

The translate button is to help you when you enter field values for a different language. It provides one field for current language and one for reference (e.g. english).

Comment: Also: https://www.languagewire.com/en/integration/sitecore-connector and http://www.lionbridge.com/sitecore/ provide services and integration into Sitecore